# How to debug err: "Uncaught (in promise) Missing Argument Unit"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I've never seen this error before.  I wrote an ugly chain of promises (below) that I suspected was throwing it, but it's even throwing when I comment-out that section.  no other promises have been fiddled-with.

Assuming it's not something obvious, how can I debug this?

error from chrome console (i've never seen `undefined:1` as a source):

```
>Uncaught (in promise) Missing argument unit       undefined:1
```

Here's the code.  Two pecularities:  (1) when I comment this block out, the error still occurs, and (2) of the two `console.log()` lines in the beginning, the first one fires before error is thrown, and second one never fires.  (1) tells me it's not the problem, but (2) tells me it is.

This was also about the only block of code I've edited since the last commit.  Other edits (all minor, none async) appear to work fine, based on `console.log()` tests.

ETA: after fully rewriting this section w/o any promises, I'm still getting the error. A bit vexed now.

```
export const startListeningToAuth = function () {

    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        console.log("BEFORE LISTENER ATTACH");
        firebaseRef.onAuth(function (authData) {
                    console.log("AFTER LISTENER ATTACH");

                    if (authData) {
                        if ('uid' in authData) {

                            //set up profile listener

                            //does user's auth ID exist in our authID:experimentUID hash?
                            firebaseRef.child('path/to/hash').once('value')

                                    .then(function (snap) {
                                        //if user is new, confirm that new users' experiment IDs are not taken
                                        if (!snap.exists()) {
                                            firebaseRef.child('path/to/profiles').once('value', function (snapshot) {

                                                //if profile exists, create new experimentUID,
                                                // write record to firebase hash (to overwrite val we wrote above)
                                                // , save, and dispatch it
                                                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                                    let newCookieUID = generateUniqueID();
                                                    Cookies.set('cookieUID', newCookieUID);

                                                    firebaseRef.child('path/to/hash').set(newCookieUID, function (err) {
                                                        dispatch(getCookieUID(newCookieUID));
                                                        return newCookieUID;
                                                    })
                                                }
                                            })
                                        } else {
                                            return snap.val()
                                        }
                                    })


                                    .then(function (snap) {

                                        //assign new ref to global var so we can turn it .off() in another function
                                        userProfileRef = new Firebase(firebaseURLs.users['renters']);

                                        //attach listener to cookieUID we came up w/
                                        var profileListener = userProfileRef.child(snap).on("value", function (snapshot) {

                                                    //if user already exists, load their profile into state
                                                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                                        dispatch({type: C.LOAD_USER_PROFILE, userProfile: snapshot.val()});
                                                    } else {

                                                        //if not, parse a new profile from their auth data
                                                        let newProfile = authPayloadToUserProfile(authData);

                                                        //write profile to firebase. no return value
                                                        createNewUserProfile(newProfile, 'renters', cookieUID);


                                                    }
                                                }
                                        )
                                    })
                                    .catch(function (err) {
                                        console.log(err)
                                    })


                        }


                    } else {
                        //if auth.on() fires null event, log user out in state
                        if (getState().userAuth.authStatus !== C.ANONYMOUS) { 
                            dispatch({type: C.LOGOUT});
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Promises have a .catch() method to deal with exceptions, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: "I wrote an ugly chain of promises that I suspected was throwing it" Without seeing the code that raises this error, it'll be hard to help you. If possible, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also keep in mind that screenshots of text are one of the least reusable ways of posting that text. Add the actual text and mark it as a `>` (block quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found what was causing this, but I'd still love to hear thoughts on WHY it happened.  the console error was so mysterious that I wanted to leave a good explanation in case someone else hit it (since there were no Google hits on this error msg)

In a React component, I had a function from `react-experiments`/`planout.js` that assigned users to A/B test groups.  I needed a UID from state to do this, so in my `mapStateToProps(state)` function, I made a global variable for storing the ID in addition to storing it in the component's props:

```
//assign user to experiment group
var exp = new SampleExperiment({'expUserID': UID});

{...component code...}

var UID;
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    UID = ;
    return {
        listing: state.listings.listingData,
        UID: UID
    }
};
```

Again, not sure why, but removing that `var UID` and changing my experiment assignment code.

Comment: Again not sure about the cause, but can point to the line in source code - https://github.com/rawls238/PlanOut.js/blob/master/es6/namespace.js#L165
I was getting this error after calling `myNameSpace.getParams()`. Error is being printed from here - https://github.com/rawls238/PlanOut.js/blob/master/es6/ops/base.js#L19